# Как лучше поступить, если нужно бросить Exception с комментарием?

Tags: java, android, инспекция-кода, исключения

Возникла ситуация при которой я достаю данные из `Intent`, необходимо обрабатывать на NullPointerException, но если вдруг кинет это Exception, то всё равно нужно крашить прогу, т.к. данное поведение недопустимо, но добавить комментарий, почему именно так вышло, я в свою очередь делаю так

```
try{
    mCPath = new CPath(intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_CPATH)); 
}catch(NullPointerException e){
    throw new NullPointerException("EXTRA_CPATH must be not null");
}
```

Но мой тимлид говорит, что так не хорошо, необходимо кинуть другой exception, а именно RuntimeException

```
try{
    mCPath = new CPath(intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_CPATH)); 
}catch(NullPointerException e){
    throw new RuntimeException("EXTRA_CPATH must be not null");
}
```

Не совсем понимаю логики, в данном контексте программы, по моему личному мнению, если приходить Null, то и кидать нужно null, просто дополнить комментарием или я не прав?

Comment: Ответ на ваш вопрос зависит от мнения, что подтверждает различие мнения вашего тимлида и у вас. Это значит, что правильного ответа не существует.

Comment: Хотелось бы, для интереса, узнать конкретное объяснение тимлида, а не просто "нехорошо". Ибо "нехорошо" - не аргумент)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Разъяснение было такого, что есть другие более подходящие эксепшины, в пример был приведён IllegalStateException, но лично я считаю, что причём тут состояние, если явно нету объекта

Comment: Код, который ловит NPE уже плох. Просто не допускайте выброс этого исключения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Немного почитав на эту тему пришол к выводу, что ловить NPE не самое лучшее решение, т.к. это может скрыть в будущем баги, а именно представьте ситуацию: допустим вы предполагаете, что какая-то переменная по известным вам причинам может быть null и вы отлавливаете это и что-то с этим всем делаете, но вполне реальна такая ситуация, что null мог прийти по абсолютно другим причинам и тогда вы можете неправильно обработать эту ситуацию, в общем это краткое пояснение почему не стоит так делать, тему можно закрывать.

Answer (score 13):

<sub>(Экстраполирую информацию из .NET, могу ошибаться.)</sub>

`NullPointerException` — это системное исключение, которое генерируется в недрах виртуальной машины Java, которое возникает при обращении по околонулевому адресу, что вообще отслеживается на уровне операционной системы. Дурной тон — и ловить исключение, и бросать его.

Ловить исключение не надо, потому что обращение к нулевому объекту — это ошибка в логике приложения. Если какая-то переменная или какое-то поле у вас null, то нужно проверять это значение, а не рассчитывать на то, что рантайм бросит NPE.

Кидать исключение не надо, потому что программисты могут ожидать, что исключение возникнет на системном уровне, а не будет вручную сгенерировано пользовательским кодом.

Как правильно поступить в вашем случае? Проверить `intent` на null, и если значение отсутствует, то бросить исключение, наиболее подходящее логически, да хотя бы `IllegalStateException`. Если значение null пришло в виде аргумента, то следует бросать `IllegalArgumentException`. И уж точно не должно быть никаких try-catch.

---

Похоже, в Java есть разные взгляды на использование исключения, но в целом преобладает моя точка зрения. См. тж.:

- [Is it okay to throw NullPointerException programatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3323006)
- [IllegalArgumentException or NullPointerException for a null parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47710)

Answer (score 2):

Все логично и прекрасно, но в стандартной библиотеке Java принято кидать `NullPointerException`:

- [`java.util.Objects.requireNonNull`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull-T-) кидает NPE.
- [`java.util.Map.put`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#put-K-V-) разрешает кидать NPE, если реализация интерфейса не поддерживает `null` как ключ или значение.
- Joshua Bloch в Effective Java (2nd ed) [Item 60](https://books.google.ru/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&lpg=PA319&ots=yZHgMnr3O_&dq=Effective%20Java%20(2nd%20ed)%20Item%2060&hl=ru&pg=PA248#v=onepage&q&f=false) пишет:

> Если при вызове null передается вместо параметра, для которого null -
>   запрещенное значение, соглашение предписывает бросать
>   NullPointerException, а не IllegalArgumentException.

- Документация на [`NullPointerException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html) сообщает:

> Приложению следует бросать экземпляры этого класса, чтобы указать на
>   недопустимое использование `null`.

Короче, NPE бросать нормально, NPE бросать похвально.

Тем не менее, демократическим путем [установлено](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3881/), что `NullPointerException` - это плохо.

Конкретно по коду в вопросе, если вы уверены, что `EXTRA_CPATH` не будет `null` никогда-никогда, а оно вдруг `null`, и остается только убить приложение, кидайте сразу `AssertionError`. Поскольку вы явно ловите unchecked exception, вы в этом не уверены, и следует проверять и закрывать приложение нормальным способом, с уведомлением пользователя.